# Facebook EOFException while posting through Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, facebook, service, broadcastreceiver

In my Application I am trying to post my **Facebook** status at a **future** time, and to accomplish that I have created a Broadcast Receiver. That I call through my **MainActivity** using **PendingIntent** and **AlarmManager**. The status is getting posted successfully if the time span is between 1 or 2 minutes. But if the time span is greater than 5 minutes then. I am getting a `java.io.EOFException` with error code of `-1` from the Facebook's Request class in response.

Please let me know how can I post a status message at later time in background. I have also tried for **Service** but in that also I am getting the same response.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way-out to do this, but it seems to work in my case but don't know that it's a systematic way or not. Earlier I was trying to post the status in the `BroadcastReciever` but was getting `java.io.EOFException`. So in order to overcome this I opened an `Activity` instead of `BroadcastReciever` and internally started the login process and did my **status posting** inside the `call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)` method.

These are the steps that I have followed:

**MainActivity.java**

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, FutureActivity.class);
in.putExtra("status", status);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mCal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

In the `MainActivity` I am calling `FutureActivity` through `PendingIntent` at a particular time that I have stored in the `mCal`.

**FutureActivity.java**

```
Status mStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mStatus = (Status) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("status");
    new FacebookLogin(this).nativeLogin(true, this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                resultCode, data);
        Session.setActiveSession(Session.getActiveSession());
    }
}

@Override
public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // here you can write the code to post the status
                mStatus.setSession(session);
                new PostStatus(mStatus).post(FutureActivity.this);
                // here you can write the code to post the status
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }
}
```

The FutureActivity is just a dummy Activity without any UI, it's main purpose is to login the user silently and getting the user's information through `newMeRequest` just in-case to make sure that we have a valid, I have tried to skip the `newMeRequest` but then I was again getting the `java.io.EOFExcepion` and inside this method I have done my coding to post the status and it was posted successfully even at a time span of **45 minutes**.

Please try this process and rate this answer if it was helpful for you.
Thank You